# Is there a better way to temporarily store lots of output data for text file (to be put in columns and rows) besides using multiple temporary files?

Tags: python, database, file, text, storage

I need to store an enormous amount of numerical data separated by commas in a text file. This txt file would be the output of a script which would do the calculations.

My problem lies in the method - it seems to be too messy and involves a lot of temporary files (I have five) which I've ensured to contain the exact number of lines to fit each data point, and which would only be merged together into one file after completion of all calculations. My code is so messy that I even have to use deque one time to cut some excess lines off a temporary file.

I use this template multiple times throughout my script(s)

```
o = open('%s_outcombined.xvg'%outfile, 'a+')
fh = open('%s_outfinal.xvg'%outfile, 'rb')
fh2 = open('%s_outfor_diff_calcs.xvg'%outfile, 'rb')
for line in fh.readlines():
   o.write(line.strip('\r\n') + fh2.readline().strip('\r\n') + '\n')
fh.close()
fh2.close()
o.close()
```

to create and combine said temporary files.

Expected results:

- A single text file which has comma-separated numerical values - this will come from calculations made for the 12 GB input file.
- A method which does not involve the usage of multiple temporary files (or if there is a way to make them hidden, I'd really like to know)
- A method of storing data which isn't time-consuming

Actual results:

- Multiple temporary files, messy code

I'm wondering whether relying on lists to store a huge amount of data (input file to be calculated is 12+ GB) is mroe time consuming, or whether I should stick to my current method, OR if you have better ideas, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do the job using batches since 12 GB are most of the time to big to store in memory.
Something like processing the first 200 lines while keeping them in memory and save them to your output file then go on to the next 200 lines until you the reach the end.

Pseudo code:

```
outputFile = new File("output")
inputFile = new File("input")

row = inputFile.readLine() # first line

while row != null:
   if outputFile.readLine() == null: # so we don't recalculate already calculated data
      columns = row.split(",")
      columns = doFirstCalculation(columns)
      columns = doSecondCalculation(columns)
      outputFile.appendLine(columns.join(","))
   else:
      print("skipped line since already calculated")
   row = inputFile.readLine() # next line
```

Just do less reads and writes which increases speed. RAM is faster than disk.

Comment: I am processing the 12 GB input file per frame (~8730 lines per frame), made possible by a for loop. The said 8730 lines are stored in a temporary file which is then processed by my code. When that frame is over, the entire temporary file gets overwritten by the next 8730 lines (next frame), so yeah, I'm already doing what you're thinking. My problem is in the creation of output files. I seem to need too many temporary files just to make sure each frame's output is stored safely.

Comment: Couldn't you just do both steps without temporary saving or do the entries in the input file have any relation to each other?